# How to know a certain row exists MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

I want to prevent users from commenting on deleted threads.
I've set a variable (let's call it 'tnum') to identify the original thread and its comments, so I can display them in a same web page.
When I delete a thread, the original thread and all comments get deleted at once
(delete from ~ where tnum is ~)

So I think I can prevent comment submission on deleted threads using that.

I want to put out an error message when there is no row in table with certain tnum value.

```
if( 'some code' ) {

error("There is no data for the thread.");

}
```

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use any database layer or ORM?

Comment: @PavelS. I don't think so. I'm a newbie. I actually don't know what those are.

Comment: Do you use something like $db = new PDO( /* connection details */ ); as in the comment OR just "standard" functions like http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php ?

Comment: By the way, my favorite tool (kind a old, but it does the job): http://dibiphp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COUNT() in MySQL to get the number of rows that match your criteria. So something like this

```
$db = new PDO( /* connection details */ );
$sth = $db->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRows FROM `table` WHERE tnum = :tnum' );
$sth->execute( array( 'tnum' => $tnum ) );
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
if( $result['numRows'] == 0 ) {
    error("There is no data for the thread.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To know if a column exist in a table you can run this query :

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table` LIKE 'fieldname';
```

Comment: The OP wants to check for a certain Row in a table, not a Column.

Comment: Sorry I'm the OP. I mixed with terms when I was composing the question (see edit history). Aleroot has done nothing wrong.